# JBPM7.XX: Error creating Task When Authentication via LDAP

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I have integrated authentication jbpm with LDAP. But, When start process instance. I cannot create user task.

Here is log server, can anyone can help?

2021-05-14 17:18:39,683 ERROR [org.jbpm.services.task.wih.LocalHTWorkItemHandler] (default task-10) Fri May 14 17:18:39 ICT 2021: Error when creating task on task server for work item id 5. Error reported by task server: There are no known Business Administrators, task cannot be created according to WS-HT specification: org.jbpm.services.task.exception.CannotAddTaskException: There are no known Business Administrators, task cannot be created according to WS-HT specification
at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.doCallbackOperationForPeopleAssignments(UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.java:298)
at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.AddTaskCommand.execute(AddTaskCommand.java:109)
at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.AddTaskCommand.execute(AddTaskCommand.java:53)
at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl$SelfExecutionCommandService.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:80)
at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl$SelfExecutionCommandService.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:65)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an "admin" group, for example

cn=admin,ou=Roles,dc=jbpm,dc=org

You may take a look at "LDAP structure" chapter and source code:

https://blog.kie.org/2021/02/migrating-jbpm-images-secured-by-ldap-to-elytron.html

Comment: Hi Gonzalo Muñoz,

Can I use other name, not like "admin"? 

Currently, I am using name like this:

 <module-option name="bindDN" value="cn=testldap,OU=Servvice,DC=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX"/>
 <module-option name="bindCredential" value="XX"/>

Comment: That's the bindDN. Apart from that, you need a group named "admin". If it clashes with other groups you already have defined, you may try to assign a different dc (for example: dc=jbpm,dc=org)

Comment: Thank you, 

I have resolved this error by config this property:

<property name="org.jbpm.ht.callback" value="jaas"/>.

Change "ldap" --> "jaas".

Comment: @MingNguyen with jaas value, you're delegating to the container to fetch information about user data.

Comment: I have other question. Can I synchozine users and groups from LDAP to JBPM and manage these information in JBPM's business-central?

Comment: No, you can't. Business central, afaik, doesn't have the capability to create/modify LDAP users and groups.

Comment: Thank you! May be we need to other system to manage them.